# Orchard CMS Custom Forms error when viewing submission

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

Using Custom Forms module ([tutorial](http://devdirective.com/post/160/how-to-create-custom-forms-in-orchard-cms-with-email-and-recaptcha)), I built a simple *Contact Us* widget. It is saving properly as I can see some data in the table `ciss_Orchard_Projections_StringFieldIndexRecord`

However, upon clicking <kbd>Submissions</kbd> link, I am getting this error:

```
The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.
```

I opened the error logs and it shows:

> 2013-01-25 01:28:01,189 [14] Orchard.DisplayManagement.Implementation.DefaultDisplayManager - NullReferenceException thrown from Action`1 by System.Action`1[[Orchard.DisplayManagement.Implementation.ShapeDisplayingContext, Orchard.Framework, Version=1.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]
>       System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>          at Orchard.Widgets.Shapes.b_*e(ShapeDisplayingContext displaying)
>          at Orchard.DisplayManagement.Implementation.DefaultDisplayManager.<>c*_DisplayClassc.b__3(Action`1 action) in c:\Users\sebros\My Projects\Orchard\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Implementation\DefaultDisplayManager.cs:line 68
>          at Orchard.InvokeExtensions.Invoke[TEvents](IEnumerable`1 events, Action`1 dispatch, ILogger logger) in c:\Users\sebros\My Projects\Orchard\src\Orchard\InvokeExtensions.cs:line 17
>       2013-01-25 01:29:39,785 [13] Orchard.DisplayManagement.Implementation.DefaultDisplayManager - NullReferenceException thrown from Action`1

Where should I start to debug this?

Can I "clean" the database to remove this offending record (perhaps)?

Comment: Yes, it does look like there is some corrupted data in there, so if you can track down what item it chokes on you should be able to restore things to a working state.

Comment: I figured out a way to work around with it. When I created the content type, I entered Widget on the Stereotype field. After removing it, the problem was gone. The code the bombs is at Widget.Wrapper.cshtml This line returns null var widgetPart = ((IContent)Model.ContentItem).As<WidgetPart>();